# Match columns in two different sheets and return multiple columns [Excel]

Tags: excel, vba

So this question looks simple but is rather complicated but I'll try my luck anyways.

There are two sheets, both have a similar first column (Code). The Code is the "master key" if you will - Each code has a lot of different information (around 200-300 columns of data) in each sheet. Also, these codes are not the same and are randomly clustered. Some of these codes do match. I've highlighted codes which match in yellow in my sample image.

So what I'm trying to do is to add all the columns of data which match with the first column (Code) to a new sheet. My sample sheets and the ideal solution would look something like this

[image: Sheet Sample and Solution]

I have tried to solve this using several =vLookup functions but I keep getting stuck. I do have several columns of data so I'm not even sure if =vLookup is something I should be using. I'm fairly new to Excel as well so I'd be glad if someone showed me in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, VLOOKUP is the correct function. Either manually type in the correct return column numbers (the third argument of the formula), or use a MATCH function.  Probably combine with IFERROR so you can check both sheets for the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your provided sample data, I created the following solution.

In Sheet "Sheet Soln" cell J1 (can be any cell and can be hidden if preferred) is this formula to identify how many matching codes are in both sheets: `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A2:A7))`  Adjust the `A2:A7` to match your actual range.  This is done so that this calculation is only performed once and then referenced later to cut down on formula calculations (increasing workbook efficiency).

Then in your Sheet Soln, cell A2 use this formula and copy down to get only the codes that are present in both sheets: `=IF(ROW(A1)>$J$1,"",INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,MATCH(1,INDEX((COUNTIF(A$1:A1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7)=0)*COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7),),0)))`

And in cell B2 use this formula and copy over and down to get the values for that code for their respective headers: `=IF($A2="","",IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A:$E,MATCH(B$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$E$1,0),FALSE),VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A:$E,MATCH(B$1,Sheet2!$A$1:$E$1,0),FALSE)))`

Comment: Thank you very much! The B2 cell shows #N/A but I know where to go now. I can fix the rest by myself. Thanks again!